# Swap characters, vertically

Tags: visual-block

Is there a handy way to do this?

My input:

```
#   A
# - B
```

Desired output:

```
# - A
#   B
```

My current solution is `xjphxkP`, which seems like a lot of keystrokes.

I realize I could record a macro, but it seems like with "visual block" selection (`ctrl-v`) there should be a way to do it with one operation, enabling the `.` operator.

Comment: I think (untested) you could simplify to `xjvpkP`